# More than one value in the [value] property

Tags: angular

I want to retrieve multiple values from my app.html file to my app.ts file.

I tried doing an event. I get the value in [value] and need to get a second value. So I tested by making a custom property as shown in the code below:

```
  <div class="select-container">
    <label>
      <select class="sort-select" (change)="applySort($event)">
        <option [value]="false" [attr.columnName]="'dateCreate'">+ to -</option>
        <option [value]="true" [attr.columnName]="'dateCreate'">- to +</option>
        <option [value]="false" [attr.columnName]="'title'">A to Z</option>
        <option [value]="true" [attr.columnName]="'title'">Z to A</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
```

To recover it, I have no problem for the [value] on the other hand I do not know how to recover the other

```
  test(event: Event): void {
    console.log((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  }
```

The problem is that I cannot retrieve this new value.

Is there a better solution or how to solve mine?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you need, but you can throw whatever you want in value.. for example [value]=“{enabled: true, columname: ‘title’}”

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 applySort(event: Event): void {
   console.log('attr',(event.target as HTMLInputElement)[(event.target as HTMLSelectElement).options.selectedIndex].getAttribute("columnName"));
    
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately, the property 'options' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Comment: In fact, you won't get an error with `//  @ts-ignore`. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Keeping most of your code, you can do like this. but it's not clean.

```js
applySort(event: HTMLSelectElement): void {
  console.log(event.value);
}
```

```html
<select class="sort-select" #select (change)="applySort(select)">
  <option [value]="false" [attr.columnName]="'dateCreate'">+ to -</option>
  <option [value]="true" [attr.columnName]="'dateCreate'">- to +</option>
  <option [value]="false" [attr.columnName]="'title'">A to Z</option>
  <option [value]="true" [attr.columnName]="'title'">Z to A</option>
</select>
```

---

A much more clear solution would be :

If you have only one field, let's use `[(ngModel)]` to get your data.

```js
selected: boolean;

constructor() {}
```

```html
<select class="sort-select" [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option [value]="false" [attr.columnName]="'dateCreate'">+ to -</option>
  <option [value]="true" [attr.columnName]="'dateCreate'">- to +</option>
  <option [value]="false" [attr.columnName]="'title'">A to Z</option>
  <option [value]="true" [attr.columnName]="'title'">Z to A</option>
</select>
<pre>{{ selected | json }}</pre> <!-- true or false -->
```

---

If you have many fields, then you should implements a `FormGroup` :

```js
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    sort: [null, Validators.required]
  });
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select class="sort-select" formControlName="sort">
    <option [value]="false" [attr.columnName]="'dateCreate'">+ to -</option>
    <option [value]="true" [attr.columnName]="'dateCreate'">- to +</option>
    <option [value]="false" [attr.columnName]="'title'">A to Z</option>
    <option [value]="true" [attr.columnName]="'title'">Z to A</option>
  </select>
</form>
{{ form.value | json }} <!-- { "sort": false } -->
```

Comment: It is much cleaner. How can I get my two values from this? Because I only get my [value]

Comment: @EleXorZ I edited my post, the first part should work. I tested it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, what I really want is to get my two values back. For example, do a console.log (event.value+ event.columnName). Your ideas only return my "true / false" value to my [value]